How can I control access to S3 private folders using cloudfront signed cookies?
I'm working on a pet project to learn AWS, and I've set up an S3 bucket with the following structure:
mybucket:
 - public:
    - ...
 - private:
    - p-1:
        - ...
    - p-2:
        - ...
    ...
    - p-xxx:
        - ...

In my application, users can publicly access all content in the public folder, while access to certain private folders is restricted. I'm considering using CloudFront to manage this access.
I know that signed cookies can help with controlling access, but if a user needs access to hundreds of private folders (p-1, p-2,...), do I need to parse all their ARNs into the signed cookies? Is there a more efficient way to handle this scenario?

The simplest answer would be to have two separate buckets, one for public and one for private.  That way it's an all or nothing type of configuration.

Thank you! I think I would also need to generate random private folder and object names to prevent users from accessing restricted content. While that approach might work, do you have any other approaches?

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do here.  In general if I need to give access to many people across many resources I'd do that with a database of some sort with a server (EC2, Lambda) in front.  Maintaining that many to many relationship in cloudfront rules sounds a bit challenging.

I already have an API server that manages the relationships between users and resources. Indeed, I have considered requiring user requests to go through the server first to verify their permissions before providing cookies or signed URLs for specific resources. However, my current approach is to parse all the resources that user can use and send it along with jwt token when they logged in my website. I think I need to reconsider the first approach when I generate cookie only when user need.
